# How to retrieve text from a button type webelement

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to retrieve text from a button type webelement using Python scripting in Selenium
The HTML code of the button looks like:

```
<button class="list-item ng-binding" ng-click="selectLineFilter(line)" type="button">
<i class="mdi mdi-domain blue" aria-hidden="true"></i>
12063497545
</button>
```

How can I retrieve the text. I used .text, it returns an error as " 'list' object has no attribute 'text' ". Please Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using `find_elements` which returns list of `WebElement` while `.text` works on single `WebElement`, So you should try using `find_element` as below :-

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.list-item.ng-binding[type='button']").text
```

Or if you want to find all elements text with the same locator, you should try using `find_elements` and iterate through in loop as below :-

```
buttons= driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("button.list-item.ng-binding[type='button']")
for button in buttons:
    button.text
```

Comment: Hey, I have five other elements like this, under clicking a single element, please help me to retrieve text of each element. I have actually traversed xpath to access each element, and when i use .text there i get the above error.

Comment: @BhuvaneshwariKumarRaja you should use looping then using `find_elements`.. try updated answer and let me know...:)

Comment: Hi I tried retrieving the entire text and then separating them into list. Thanks anyway.. :)

    alllinestext = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".dropdown.line-filter-dropdown.shown").text
        activtext = str(alllinestext)
        self.textcheckval = activtext.splitlines()

Answer (score 0):

use .GetAttribute("innerHTML")

Answer (score 0):

you can use the concept of this Java code :

WebDriver driver;

String a = driver.findelement(by.xpath("")).getText(); //use css or id attribute

System.out.println(a); //this will print the text present on the button.